# Implementing autofill in a chrome extension using data from chrome.storage.api

Tags: javascript, search, google-chrome-extension, full-text-search, autofill

I am trying to make a search bar in a chrome extension that uses data stored using the chrome.storage.api. I want the search bar to automatically recommend relevant(matching) options on each key press using the data in the storage(like google autocomplete). I have thought about using tries but tries are too memory intensive. Is there any other way to implement this using javascript?

Comment: How you can make this work depends on how you're storing the data (single object, multiple object with the key as the search term) and how you want the search to work (full key matches / partial matches)

Comment: I am storing information in the form of array of json objects {X, Y, Z} where I want to base my search on X and Y. Along with this, I require full key matches.

Comment: You can simply make a call to `chrome.storage.<local/sync>.get(searchedTerm, function(result){....})` and display the result is there is any and the `searchTerm` hasn't changed (the callback is async).

Comment: I wrongly interpreted your question. I would need partial search also.

Comment: In that case, retrieve all the objects from the storage when the extension is started and search through the objects' keys to see if any one of them partially matches. You can use `chrome.storage.<local/sync>.get(null, function(items){})` to get them all.